# Can the i7-11800H clock to 5.0GHZ?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, overclocking, turbo-boost

The Intel [specifications](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/213803/intel-core-i711800h-processor-24m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html) for the i7-11800h processer says that the max turbo frequency is 4.6GHZ. In the bios under the overview section, it says: maximum clock speed: 5.0GHZ

When I first saw it, I thought it was a typo but something in the program ThrottleStop caught my eye. Under "turbo overclocking" it says +4 and under turbo ratio limits, the single core has a value of 46 which corresponds to 4.6GHZ. So if we add 46+4 we get 50 which means 5.0GHZ and that accords with the BIOS.

What does this actually mean, does it mean that the CPU may be overclocked to 5.0GHZ without an issue?

[image]

Comment: Because you have a `H` chip, it will be locked at 4.6GHz. If you had a `HK` chip, you would be permitted to exceed the max turbo clock speed.

Comment: @spikey_richie Locked by what, the bios? I already disabled the CFG & Overclocking locks in the bios by special tools

Comment: Locked by Intel. Non-K chips are manufacturer-locked to be non-overclockable. There are some workarounds for some generations (SkyOC on 6th gen, BCLK overclocking on 12th) but generally, if you want to overclock, you have to pay extra because Intel says so.

Comment: @gronostaj Are there workarounds in my case?

Comment: I'm not aware of any.

Comment: Even if we set all the "politics" aside, there is no way to tell if a CPU can be overclocked to a specific frequency or undervolted or whatever. By definition, it is outside the specs. You can only try.

Comment: It all depends on cooling and the individual silicone. A overclock to 5Ghz from 4.6Ghz is a pretty substantial overclock on air

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HK series is fully unlocked. The 11800H supports a feature called limited overclocking. In the ThrottleStop Turbo Ratio Limits section, you should be able to add +4 to the default multipliers that are listed. The defaults go from 46 to 42 depending on how many cores are active. If you are overclocking, you can change these to a maximum of 50 to 46. Make sure the Speed Shift Max value is set to 50 if you are overclocking. It will be a challenge to keep the CPU from overheating and thermal throttling if you set the 8 core active multiplier to 46. This answer is based on my experience as the developer of ThrottleStop.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer-

In the TPL (Turbo Power Limits) window, under miscellaneous, the speed shift max  is 46:

[image]

To be able to change it to 50, the `MMIO` box must be checked (don't forget to Apply). After that, close the TPL window and re-open it and it shall show "Max 50". To actually change the speed shift max value, check the speed shift box and change it to the desired value:

[image]

Keep in mind that this does not automatically overclock the CPU if you set it to a value higher than 46. To manually overclock the CPU, you need to increase the values under "Turbo Ratio Limits" within the FIVR window:

[image]

Finally, the Windows operating system might restrict the CPU from reaching the new clock speeds on the Balanced Power Plan. Changing the power plan to "High Performance" removes this restriction.

Note: Overclocking might require increase in the core voltage.